# Date time error in .net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

while passing date in M/d/yyyy format in V.S 2012 throwing exception while works fine in 2008 please suggest how to fix this.Below is the code

```
 String date = drpMonth.SelectedItem.Value + "/" + drpDay.SelectedItem.Value + "/" + drpYear.SelectedItem.Value;
            try
            {


                objUsers.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
            }
```

Comment: Please instead of some random concatenation show exact string value (like `var date = "4/22/2045"`) and show your current culture.

Comment: If you already have the parts seperated like that, why not use [new DateTime(year, month day)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx)?

Comment: I am from Microsoft .NET Framework team. What version of .NET Framework were you targeting in VS 2008 and which version of .NET are you targeting in VS 2012? Thanks, Varun

Comment: @Varun I have started my project in VS 2008 in 3.5 framework later due to some reason i continue it in VS2010 but now when i run my project in VS2012 it shows error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
int m = int.Parse( drpMonth.SelectedItem.Value);
int d = int.Parse(drpDay.SelectedItem.Value);
int y = int.Parse(drpYear.SelectedItem.Value);
objUsers.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(y, m, d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
String strMonth =drpMonth.SelectedItem.Value;
String strDay = drpDay.SelectedItem.Value;
String date = ((strMonth.Length!=2)?"0"+strMonth :strMonth)+ "/" + ((strDay.Length!=2)?"0"+strDay :strDay)+ "/" + drpYear.SelectedItem.Value;
try
{
    objUsers.DateOfBirth =  DateTime.ParseExact(date,"MM/dd/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```